# cowboy 'GET' request variables values

Tags: erlang, cowboy

Please tell me, how I can get the variables values of the GET request
I do so:

```
{Method, Req2}       = cowboy_req:method(Req),
{FwdIPRaw, Req3}     = cowboy_req:header(<<"x-forwarded-for">>, Req2),
{ClientCookie, Req4} = cowboy_req:cookie(<<"cook">>, Req3),
{ok, GetVals, Req5}  = cowboy_req:qs_vals(Req4),
MessageId   = proplists:get_value(<<"mid">>, GetVals),
EchoName    = proplists:get_value(<<"m">>, GetVals),
{ok, Req5, State}.
```

But I get an error: `qs_vals - undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For current cowboy version (0.9.0) [documentation says](https://github.com/extend/cowboy/blob/0.9.0/src/cowboy_req.erl#L292) that `cowboy_req:qs_vals(Req4)` returns `{QsVals, Req5}` where QsVals can be [] (empty list).
So try 0.9.0 cowboy version and fix call `{ok, GetVals, Req5}  = cowboy_req:qs_vals(Req4)` to `{GetVals, Req5}  = cowboy_req:qs_vals(Req4)`.